# npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall rename

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Like week ago I installed local package globaly by command npm i -g path.
It worked fine since today. I tried to use npm i -g path again and i get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path "user"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\js2cp-28011c0d\node_modules\fs-extra
npm ERR! dest "user"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\fs-extra-d19736e5   
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '"user"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\js2cp-28011c0d\node_modules\fs-extra' -> '"user"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\fs-extra-d19736e5'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     "user"\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-27T07_39_50_112Z-debug.log
```

I wanted to go into "user"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ but I cant find folder ./.staging inside the node_modules folder.

Any ideas what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do couple things to fix this quickly

a. clean cache: `npm cache clean --force`

b. delete package.lock

if those two doesnt help youl need to be a bit tricky

c. delete node-modules and then npm install againe (hope this will help)

d. delete node with npm and reinstall it

mostly the a and b will solve the problem for ya!

Comment: I have done a,b,c and still not helped. It looks like I have to do d and just hope.

Comment: @RobinGrundel dont forget to delete all npm from the appData

Comment: yeah done that and it works. But I sitll don't get what caused it, or why just today it stopped working. btw Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was accidentally using node 14, while node 16 was the one I was working with before. After switching to node 16 again the problem was resolved. Might be worth a check before reinstalling node.